# How do I change the colour of the red close button in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, themes

Is there some way to modify the colour of the "Close" button in Windows 8?

On several applications, an active window displays a *not-so-subtle* red.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the color of the close button but you have to edit the Theme file. 
Look in : `C:\Windows\Resources\Themes`

But the best way is to search the internet for custom themes and apply them to your Windows 8 OS.

---

It is not easy to edit the Theme file in Windows if you do not know what you are doing. First you will need a editor, I do not have experience in this but searching the web I found Ave's Windows Style Builder, it might do the trick. But you can [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=modify%20the%20theme%20file&rlz=1C1LEND_enDE506DE506&oq=modify%20the%20theme%20file&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=122&espv=210&newwindow=1&q=windows%20theme%20editor&safe=off) for others just put `Windows Theme Editor` in Google Search. Then I would suggest to watch some tutorials on Youtube or Google. After you feel a bit confident you might modify a existing theme, just copy it and change the values/shapes. Then repeat Testing until the style built as like you want.

Comment: Can you point to any resources to modify the theme file? I tried [installing a few custom themes](http://www.howtogeek.com/168270/how-to-install-custom-themes-and-visual-styles-in-windows/) with no success.

Comment: Why didn't you have success ? It is good described how to install a theme in the link you posted. Here are some youtube videos: http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=how+to+install+themes&page=&utm_source=opensearch

Comment: For over 20 themes I tried, the red close button persisted.